# Android rotate imageview in layout file

Tags: android, android-imageview

In my app each of the screens has a background image. I want to use the same image for portrait and landscape, but to make it look decent I need to rotate the image 90 degrees when in landscape so that it does not get stretched to fill the screen.

My solution was to just create two copies of the image one for portrait that I put in drawable-port and one for landscape that I put in drawable-land. Now that I have many different backgrounds my solution of just embedding a second copy of the image in my apk is causing the apk size to be much larger then needed.

How can I support rotated images, preferably in pure XML. In code I suppose you could just rotate the image before onStart and it would work, but I would really rather keep it in the XML if possible.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this in XML.  But if you created a custom class that inherited from whichever view you're applying the background to (say, RelativeLayout), then you could do something like

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int newWidth, int newHeight, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
    if (newWidth > newHeight) {    // landscape
        // rotate the background
    }
}
```

This way, you only have to implement the rotation once and all of your views would auto-rotate their backgrounds.